# How to evenly space (space-between) nested divs as if they were on same level

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

can i have flex's `space-between` work on nested divs?
ie the columns should be evenly spaced without changing the html markup as in this example:

```
<Column />
<div>
   <Column />
   <Column />
</div>
```

Comment: Missing your real html, here is an example using display:contents : https://jsfiddle.net/wLh13jt7/ That is the way i can think about via plain CSS at first thought.

Answer (score 0):

No, the flex properties would only apply to div's. Here you can add the specific flex properties on div itself to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: expected this answer. since the html is generated, i'll have to dig into the cms and see if i find a solution there to make them siblings. thanks!

Comment: @Jonas if you are able to modify css of the parent element, you can then use css to apply the flex properties to the child elements, using css selectors. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#combinators)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `display: contents;` property to the inner wrapper.

```css
.wrapper{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .column{
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
    .inner_wrapper{
      display: contents;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="inner_wrapper">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="inner_wrapper">
      <div class="column"></div>
      <div class="column"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```